# Connecting 4 pin PSU cable to an ASUS motherboard

Tags: power-supply

I have purchased a [G7 780W power extreme power supply](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/g7-780w-atx-pc-power-supply-n34hc) and I have a 4 pin EATX SOCKET on my motherboard it was required with the old power supply but with the new power supply it has two 4 pin connectors that say CPU on them.

Do I connect one of these to the EATX Socket as I am confused and I do not want to power it up until I find out that it is correct to connect one of the 4 pin CPU connectors to the 4 pin EATX Socket on my ASUS motherboard.

Comment: Post a link to the PSU please.

Answer (score 2):

I believe only one of those 4 pin connectors will fit, they are keyed to the particular socket.

You will only need to plug in one of them, the second is for when you have an 8 pin CPU power socket and the connectors will usually fit side by side.

Comment: IME the two 4-pin connectors from the PSU will usually snap together and thereby "act like" an 8-pin connector.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an "EATX SOCKET".

In addition to the main power socket (the 24-pin one) your motherboard *may* have one or more of the following:

- A 4-pin socket known as [ATX12V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#ATX12V_1.x)
- A 8-pin socket known as [EPS12V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#EPS12V)

Whatever your motherboard needs is what you need to connect. Note that some power supplies give you [ATX12V and EPS12V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#EPS12V) compatibility in one:

> ...many power supply makers implement the 8-pin connector as two combinable 4-pin connectors to ensure backwards compatibility with ATX12V motherboards.

The connectors are all keyed so, unless you're jamming them in with brute force, you can't get this wrong.  Just make sure *all* power sockets are connected.